# Angular Component stops "reading" it's CSS file

Tags: css, angular, html

I have an Angular 6 app, and one of my components suddenly stoped "reading" its css file.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-vendor-client-settings',
templateUrl: './vendor-client-settings.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./vendor-client-settings.component.css'],
animations: [SlideFromLeftAnimation]
})
```

the file seems to be alright, the names are the same.
it doesnt work on ng serve nor webpack build.

what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: try: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component (where the styleurls/selector/templateurl etc are)

Comment: I've tried it, not working for me :(

Comment: well. Then u gotta post some code so i can take a look or just start with an empty css-file, add one css-class. keep adding until it breaks. and you will find the answer.

Comment: I also got your problem. I solved that by deleting CSS file , then I create it and import it again

Comment: ive tried to just copy to css content into a new .css file. didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i've found the problem in the code - someone accidentally inserted all the css content inside a media query. thats why I couldn't see any of it. problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this try to add  css in this component dynamically .
    That is on Init

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadStyle('your path');
 } 

     loadStyle(src)
  {
  let link = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = src;
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = 'text/css';
let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  let links = head.getElementsByTagName('link');
  let style = head.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
  head.insertBefore(link, style);
  }
```

Comment: That's a bandaid fix, not a root cause solution.

Comment: Well its the problem of DOM ,You can even increase your loadtime time so that your css gets loaded when your component is in DOM.